# what is the name assigned by terraform to reference this resource?

Tags: terraform

Could any please answer my question : whether it is a) azurerm_resource_group  b) test c) dev

```
 resource "azurerm_resource_group" "dev"
    
        {
            name     = "test"
            location = "canadacentral"
        }
```

Comment: What name are you referring to? The Terraform object reference or the name of the (eventually) deployed azure resource? In the first case it would be: "dev". In the last case it would be "test"

Answer (score 1):

A block `resource "azurerm_resource_group" "dev"` declares a resource with the address `azurerm_resource_group.dev` in the current module, so `azurerm_resource_group.dev` is how you'd refer to this object from expressions elsewhere in the same module.

The `name` argument inside the block is part of the data sent to the Azure provider, so it's up to the Azure provider to decide how to make use of it. In this particular case, I believe the provider will send that value as part of its requests to the Azure API to create, update, or delete this object, and so it'll become the name of the object as far as the remote system is concerned, and not the name of the object as far as Terraform is concerned.

Comment: So  in this case which one will be correct choice?  b "dev" or c "test" ?

Answer (score -1):

More easy to understand:

- `azurerm_resource_group` is the official name that the Azure developer who created the code for the provider gave it.
- `dev` is the name you have given to the resource and is the **local name**. This is used to refer to this resource from elsewhere in the same Terraform module, but has no significance outside that module's scope. This is called "Resource names". (https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/syntax#resource-syntax)
- `test` is the Name which should be used for this Resource Group. (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/resource_group#name). But I think it is easier to see it in another resource. In the resource `aws_ami`, the name is the Region-unique name for the AMI.(https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ami#name)

So to summarize the answer is `dev`. Since even if you put it on, terraform uses it to reference.

Comment: The last line of the answer messes up the rest of the post. It assumes an answer to which name the OP is talking about. Secondly, What does 'Since even if you put it on' means?

Comment: @MyName The last line summarize the question: What is the name assigned by terraform to reference this resource? Is c) dev . "Since even if you put it on, terraform uses it to reference." I mean that even if you write it, terraform uses it as an internal reference